# MySQL replace a whole string based off part of the string?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have the following MySQL data

1. userfiles/user/JohnSmith/2013_Thanksgiving_Final.jpg
2. userfiles/user/JaneJohnson/2013_Thanksgiving_Final.jpg
3. userfiles/user/BobbyLee/2013_Thanksgiving_Final.jpg

Is there a way to change it to?

1. globalfiles/2016_Thanksgiving_Final.jpg
2. globalfiles/2016_Thanksgiving_Final.jpg
3. globalfiles/2016_Thanksgiving_Final.jpg

I was thinking doing something like this?

```
 UPDATE user__attributes SET value = REPLACE(value, REGEXP '2013_Thanksgiving_Final', 'globalfiles/2016_Thanksgiving_Final.jpg') WHERE value LIKE '%2013_Thanksgiving_Final%';
```

I was thinking if I used REGEXP, it would target the whole string, based off just a piece of it to replace? Though I threw an error attempting this.

Thanks!

Comment: you want remove the part  'yserFiles/user/JohnSmith/  and repalce with globlfiles for all the user where there is 2013_Thanksgiving_Final.jpg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want add globalfiles at existing files name the You don't need regexp but 
simply replace

```
UPDATE user__attributes 
SET value = REPLACE(value, '2013_Thanksgiving_Final.jpg', 'globalfiles/2016_Thanksgiving_Final.jpg' ) 
WHERE value LIKE '%2013_Thanksgiving_Final%';
```

if you want substitute the userfiles/user/*/2013_Thanksgiving_Final.jpg with globalfiles/2016_Thanksgiving_Final.jpg  you should use

```
UPDATE user__attributes 
SET value = globalfiles/2016_Thanksgiving_Final.jpg
WHERE value LIKE '%2013_Thanksgiving_Final%';
```

Comment: Ah I was going about it all wrong, thank you for the help!